# Hsqldb Server, alias does not exist

Tags: server, hsqldb

According to the log the server was startet with alias "myrepos" as expected.
But if I try to connect to this alias, I get an error, also visible in the log (last line).

What could be the cause?

```
[Server@28fc19eb]: Initiating startup sequence...
[Server@28fc19eb]: Server socket opened successfully in 6 ms.
[Server@28fc19eb]: Database [index=0, id=0, db=file:/Users/t..../myrepos, alias=myrepos             ] opened sucessfully in 1238 ms.
[Server@28fc19eb]: Startup sequence completed in 1247 ms.
[Server@28fc19eb]: 2016-04-08 10:32:33.871 HSQLDB server 2.3.3 is online on port 9001
[Server@28fc19eb]: To close normally, connect and execute SHUTDOWN SQL
[Server@28fc19eb]: From command line, use [Ctrl]+[C] to abort abruptly
[Server@28fc19eb]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @2304d78b,5,HSQLDB Connections @28fc19eb]]: database alias=myrepos does not exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I had spaces behind the database name in my configuration, which had been incorporated to the alias: 'alias=myrepos             ]'
So, the alias actually wasn't `"myrepos"` but `"myrepos             "`

Comment: Could you please help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53995148/java-sql-sqlexceptiongeneral-error-database-alias-does-not-exist-hsqldb ?

Comment: your question is not there anymore. Hope you found a solution.